# QIDI x-one2 : Fan screws not holding filament feeder stepper motor in place

Tags: extruder, motor

I noticed a knocking noise one day on my QIDI and things seemed fine at first glance, then 7 hours later my print only had 3 layers. So I figured it was a jam, and I cleaned it out but every now and then I heard the knock again which cause incomplete prints. When I went back to remove the front facing cooling fan I noticed one of the screws that go through the fan to the stepper motor wasn't secure. This was causing the filament guide to rock out of place periodically until it got worse and worse.

I've been trying for hours but the screw just won't "catch" on the stepper motor that feeds the filament into the extruder. The screws aren't stripped because I can take the motor off and screw them directly into it with no problem. It's as if they aren't long enough anymore or that they're bent.

Has anyone else had this problem & found a solution that works consistently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this same problem and my solution was to push the motor as close as I could up to where the screw goes, because they weren’t lined up. I hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you @ColeC1821 I did actually end up doing that, but it lead me to my overall resolution.... which was taking a small flat head screwdriver and grinding down the recessed area where the screws are mounted. I wish I had a precise measurement and process, but it was probably about 4mm of material shaven off and then the screws were finally able to reach the motor mounts. 

This was all caused because of my lack of patience. QIDI was sending me replacement fans, but it was going to take two weeks to get to me. So I got a similar part, and the recessed depth was too shallow.